# waitForSelector timeout option doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js, puppeteer

I keep trying to use a variable as the timeout value but it never seems to work.

```js
var b = data1.raw_time.split(' ');
console.log(b[1]);
let time = parseInt(b[1], 10) * 60000;
console.log(time);
message.channel.send('Server is in queue for ' + b[1] + ' minutes!');

try {
    await page.waitForSelector('.main #confirm', { timeout: time });
    await page.click('.main #confirm');
} catch (error) {
    message.channel.send('Server start sequence was aborted');
}
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What are the values that are logged (time and b[1])?

Comment: I have a catch (err) but I never printed the error to console maybe I'll try that next time the values of b[1] is 2 and time is 120000.

Comment: Your code has a brace at the end that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The timeout accepts a Number value. You should try logging the time variable and its typeof right above the try statement to see what's happening all the time.

Comment: Yah I logged type of it showed number